# [UWP]- OnActivated Event not calling

Tags: windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp

I have windows 8 app with notifications enabled. it works great in windows 8, 8.1 and in windows 10 machine too.
But i got the problem is when user taps on notification it is getting the launch attributues from LAunchEvent in windows 8 and 8.1 apps and based on the launch parameter of toast notification as expected. where as if i run the application in windows 10 machine if user taps on notification I am unable to read the **Launch** attributes of toast notification.
So can anyone please guide me what should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

See the section on "Handling activation from a toast notification" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiles_and_toasts/archive/2015/07/09/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10.aspx

If you're using the new Win 10 templates or custom actions, then you'll have to handle the launch events/arguments in the OnActivated Handler.